# run code with all variable at zero

Tags: swift

I want the following code to run even if the array is 0 (has no data in it).

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell?
    //let dataArray = ["1","1","1","1"]

    //first table
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        print("DataArray result is: \(self.dataArray)")
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell?
        let previewDetail = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell!.textLabel!.text = previewDetail


    }

    //secont dable (same as first for the purpose of the exercise
    if tableView == self.tableView1 {
        print("DataArray result is: \(self.dataArray)")
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell?
        let previewDetail = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell!.textLabel!.text = previewDetail


    }

    return cell!
}
```

I am downloading some data, for which I have to wait for, but in the meantime the above code, which needs the downloaded data, is creating an error since it can't run without data. So, is there a way to run the above without the downloaded data?

Comment: No, if it "needs the downloaded data", then there's not a way to run it without the downloaded data. You'll have to change it so that it doesn't need the downloaded data, and then it can run.

Comment: Create temporary data to display until the real data arrives?  You just have to decide what should be shown while waiting.

Comment: It shouldn't need to run without data. Your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` should be returning zero until the data is available, in which case `cellForRowAtIndexPath` won't run. Can you post what you have in that function?

Comment: I am now showing the full code , I acturally have two tables and it crashes in the second table at the previewDetail constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cellForRowAtIndexPath method won't run unless there is at least one row to display. You'll need to change the numberOfRowsInSection method as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let array = downloadedDataArray where array.count > 0 {
        return array.count
    }
    return 1
}
```

In this case, the cellForRowAtIndexpath method will run but you'll have to be careful here since there won't be any data in the downloadedDataArray and so, you'll get an error if you try to access that data. You'll need to perform the same check as above in here also :-

```
    if let array = downloadedDataArray where array.count > 0 {
        //Your data cell here
    }else{
        //Show a dummy cell when download is in progress
    }
```

When, the download is completed, you can reload the table to display your data cells.